# Different index actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Lots of application i see and work in often ends up with lots of if condition in there index actions.

ex:

```
class TaskController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:project_id]
      Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks
    else
      Task.scoped
    end
  end

end
```

What's best practice for this?

My idea is to use routes instead and have one action called `index` and another called `index_by_project` and then point to the last one if `params[:project_id]` is present. Is this a good ide and how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url are **very** important, they make things clear in your head and in your code.

If you sometimes need `params[:project_id]`, it cries for nested routes.

So you'd end up with:

```
/tasks
/projects/:project_id/tasks
```

Comment: Yes exactly what i usually ends up with. But if I will point `/projects/:project_id/tasks` to `TasksController#index_by_project` is there a better way than `get '/projects/:project_id/tasks' => 'tasks#index_by_project'`.

Comment: Should simply be 'index' otherwise there is non sense to nesting